# bash if "$1" == "0" is always false when running function for bash prompt

Tags: bash, function, if-statement, prompt

I have been struggling with this for a long time.
Trying to change colour as part of my prompt depending on the exit code of the last command.

I have reduced my prompt to a minimal example:

```
Red="\[\033[31m\]"
Green="\[\033[32m\]"
Reset="\[\033[0m\]"

statColour(){
    if [[ "$1" == "0" ]]; then
        echo -e "${Green} $1 "
    else
        echo -e "${Red} $1 "
    fi
}

export PS1="$(statColour \$?)What Colour? $Reset"
```

And results in red always being used despite the fact the number is clearly 0 in the first instance.

[image]

I have tried `[` and `$1 -eq 0` with no success. Why isn't this working?

Comment: You have to single quote `PS1`, or it'll be evaluated just once instead of every time a prompt is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Red="\033[35m"
Green="\033[32m"
Reset="\033[0m"

statColour(){
    if [[ $1 = 0 ]]; then
        echo -e "${Green} $1 "
    else
        echo -e "${Red} $1 "
    fi
}

export PS1="\$(statColour \$?)What Colour? $Reset"
#           ^
```

1. Color definitions changed
2. Call of `statColour` is now done every time, and not only once.
3. `if [[ ]]` optimized

Comment: oh wow I can't believe I missed that. I didn't even look because the exit status number was changing so I assumed it was being called ever time. Does $1 become global or something? How can the $1 be changing when the function is only called once?

Comment: SO this is the right answer but would still like to know how the exit code was still updating in the echo $1 when the function was only being run once.

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation why you always take the *false* branch:

You are calling `statColour` with `\$?` as argument. The backslash ensures, that the `$` is taken literally (and not as the start of a parameter expanson), so you have in effect the literal string `$?`. Since `?` is a wildcard character, it is undergoing filename generation, i.e. the parameter is replaced by all files where the name is a `$`, followed by a single character. If there are no such files in your directory (which is probably the case), the string `$?` is passed literally to statColour.

Inside `statColour`, you wrote

```
[[ "$1" == "0" ]]
```

which means that you ask, whether the string `$?` is equal to the string `0`. This is never the case, hence the comparision is always false.

For your problem, you could try this approach (not tested, so you may have to debug it a bit):

```
statColour() {
  # Fetch the exit code of the last program
  local last_exit_code=$?
  if ((last_exit_code == 0)) # Numeric comparision
  then
    .....
  else
    ...
  fi
  # Preserve the exit code
  return $last_exit_code
}
```

and set the prompt as

```
PS1='$(statColour) '"$Reset"
```

The single quotes ensure that `statColour` is evaluated dynamically, while `$Reset` is in double quotes since it is OK to evaluate it statically.

Comment: $? seems to be the correct exit codes in my script.
The echo $1 is outputting 0 and then 127 for a bad command right after.

Comment: $? never expands into file paths anywhere I used it. When would this happen?
Also in my script, you need to escape \$? or it will be processed once and always be 0.

Comment: @Brad : Simple example : Copy and paste the following command sequence: `touch '$r'; echo \$?`. The echo will expand to `$r`.

Comment: @Brad : In the code you posted, you execute the function `statColour` exactly once, i.e. by the time `PS1` is defined, instead of during every invocation. The answer by Wiimm showed one way to fix it, but overlooked the problem with the unescaped question mark.  He should have at least passed the status code as `\$\?`. My answer uses a different approach (which IMO is a bit clearer, but this is of course a matter of taste), and with this, you don't need to worry about escaping `$?`.